# Add custom URl parameter to Experience Site home page

Tags: community, experience-builder-page

I want to add a custom URL parameter to the home page automatically when it's loaded after successful authentication.

The value for the URL parameter should be based on a field value in user record.

Is this possible to configure in Experience Builder?

Comment: Which field value in the user record are you referring to?

Comment: @Swetha - I wanted to set the LanguageLocaleKey and LocaleSidKey using a URL parameter when the home page is loaded.